# React native authorization

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a react-native mobile application with login. What would be the best way to implement authorization. I am doing the following:

1. A request is sent from this URL with username & password. 
   www.xyz.com/Token
2. If authorized, Token is returned and stored it in Realm database.
3. Every time the app is opened auth token is picked from realm if expired a user log out & login screen is shown to the user.

Now I do not want the user to log in every time after the token expires and how can I securely store the token instead of realm.

If someone can suggest a proper workflow of login or if there is any package available that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah! Check out [react-native-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0)

Comment: But this needs to create an account with auth0 that will manage the whole flow whereas I have my custom web API.@mstiggle